# Adding firebase with Xcode as a package dependency fails due to GUI flaw

Tags: xcode, firebase

I like to add ***some*** dependencies from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk repository as Google recommends.

When selecting the dependencies needed and scrolling down the "add to Target" dropdown keeps resetting all the time when scrolling back up again. I can only add all dependencies or keep using cocoapods.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a confusion over what you're specifying here. Just specify firebase-ios-sdk and the desired version, and stop: one line in the package dependencies. So you download the whole package.

But you don't want to *use* the whole package, so in the Link Library With Build Phase for your app target, *that* is where you specify which libraries you want to use.

Comment: It just says in the official Firebase documentation: File > Add Packages ---> "Choose the Firebase libraries you want to include in your app." So I figured...

Comment: I guess it's a question of whom you're going to believe. :) You can do what we do in our app, or you can keep flipping those popup menus until the cows come home.

Comment: In this very second I am already following you matt, removing not needed dependencies from "link binary with libraries".